# Installing Mysql innodb cluster v8 with ansible

Tags: mysql, ansible, mysql-python, mysql-innodb-cluster

I want to install mysql v8 with ansible by downloading repo ( mysql-apt-config_0.8.15-1_all.deb )
and install it with dpkg,when i want to manually without ansible install, it prompts a window to choose version and some configs and then i should click ok for adding the repo and updating the apt repo and so on

The problem comes in when i want to install repo and mysql package with ansible

Now  how can i do this and solve my problem with prompt window in ansible?

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: This is not related to MySQL InnoDB Cluster